# Php action difference with "echo"

Tags: php, action

Could someone explain the difference between these two statements:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

I am not seeing a difference in behavior.

Comment: If you leave it blank, its fine, without the echo, form is posted to the same page, as no action is defined, so you can leave the action attribute blank or don't declare that at all...

Comment: @Mr. Alien.  I do not understand your reply. Please clarify what you mean by "no action is defined".

Comment: in 1st case output will be `action=""` in second `action="path/on/server"`. Echo will display value, without echo it won be outputed

Comment: Since you dont use the word echo, your action attribute will have no value which is equivalent to not defined, so the form is posted on the same page, whereas using php, you do the same thing, so just delete your action attribute in general

Comment: So what happens to the string assigned to action in the first case? Why does action do nothing in this case? (@MarkS: why is action equivalent to "" in the first case)

Comment: Who's the d-b that down voted a question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is simple.

The first piece if code doesn't prints anything.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

So the `action` parameter is empty and by default browsers submit the form to the same site, what likely would be the same value `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` returns.

If you use the second piece of code the return of `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` would be  echoed out and the browser submits the form to the same site, like above.

**Example**

If your site was called `form.php`. The first piece of code would produce:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

The browser sees action is empty and sends the form data to the site, `form.php`

And the second piece would produce:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
```

Comment: Can you explain why the first returns action=""? The return of htmlspecialchars is a string. So it should be action="<somestring>". In the second case won't it result in action="echo <somestring>". Maybe I don't understand the combo of action and htmlspecialchars(<form>)

Comment: htmlspecialchars returns a string, but you need a funtction to write this returned value out (eg echo) . The return of a php function is not automatically written out. Another example: Try to do a simple calculation, you will see the result won't show up until you use echo.

Answer (score 2):

The first example will output, because `htmlspecialchars` does not output anything, it simply returns the processed content.

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Which will simply submit the form to the current page.

The second example will output something like

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
```

Where `page.php` is the current script (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)).

Because a blank action submits the form to the current page, and using your `echo` statement will print out a route to the current page, the two will result in the same thing.